# coding error on my swift project missing expected/parameter&&seperator

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, swift2, youtube-data-api

I have an issue issue on my project, it keeps requesting expected parameter type following `:` . & expected separator I left a comment of the issues right above where I am getting requested to insert them. I appreciate for the help.

```
        // expected parameter type following ':' &             expectedseperator ,
        func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURLRequest, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in

            if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil {

            // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary.
            let resultsDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            let items: AnyObject! = resultsDict["items"] as AnyObject!
            let firstItemDict = (items as! Array<AnyObject>)[0] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            let snippetDict = firstItemDict["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            var desiredValuesDict: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
            desiredValuesDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
            desiredValuesDict["description"] = snippetDict["description"]
            desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]


            desiredValuesDict["playlistID"] = ((firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["relatedPlaylists"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["uploads"]

            self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValuesDict)

            self.tblVideos.reloadData()

            ++self.channelIndex
            if self.channelIndex < self.desiredChannelsArray.count {
            self.getChannelDetails(useChannelIDParam)
            }
            else {
            self.viewWait.hidden = true
            }

            } else {
            println("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            println("Error while loading channel details: \(error)") }

            })
    }        
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining function error using generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010256/defining-function-error-using-generics)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to call the function `performGetRequest` but you're defining it with the `func` at the beginning.

If that's not your intention maybe you're trying to define the function but you must be careful with the completion handler. You can see the correct way of doing that [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/).

Finally, here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342428/error-trying-to-perform-a-get-request-in-swift-2-0) of a function with the same name and a similar problem. I don't know if your code is based on that but it could be clarifying to take a look at that question and its answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var desiredChannelsArray = ["eminemvevo", "Google", "disney"]

    var channelIndex = 0

    var channelsDataArray: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>.Type?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }  class helper {
        func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURL!, completion: (data: NSData?, HTTPStatusCode: Int, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
            request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

            let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)})})


            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func getChannelDetails(useChannelIDParam: Bool) {
        var urlString: String!
        if !useChannelIDParam {
            urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails,snippet&forUsername=\(desiredChannelsArray[channelIndex])&key=\(apiKey)"
        } else {
        }

        let targetURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

        func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURL!, completion: (data: NSData?, HTTPStatusCode: Int, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

            if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil{
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary.

                let resultsDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>}

            let items: AnyObject! = resultsDict["items"] as AnyObject!
            let firstItemDict = (items as! Array<AnyObject>)[0] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            let snippetDict = firstItemDict["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            var desiredValuesDict: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
            desiredValuesDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
            desiredValuesDict["description"] = snippetDict["description"]
            desiredValuesDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]


            desiredValuesDict["playlistID"] = ((firstItemDict["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["relatedPlaylists"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["uploads"]

            self.channelsDataArray.append(desiredValuesDict)

            self.tblVideos.reloadData()

            ++self.channelIndex
            if self.channelIndex < self.desiredChannelsArray.count {
                self.getChannelDetails(useChannelIDParam)
            }
            else {
                self.viewWait.hidden = true
            }
        } else {

            print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            print("Error while loading channel details: \(error)") }
    }
}
}
```